# Electron - Open Folder Dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, directory, electron

I want the user to be able to pick a folder from the folder dialog box.
So far, I've tried following [this](https://jaketrent.com/post/select-directory-in-electron/) tutorial unsuccessfully.
I got stuck on the part of

```
exports.selectDirectory = function () {
  // dialog.showOpenDialog as before
}
```

What do I need to do in order to retrieve the full path of the selected folder?
Thanks!

Comment: Well, I solved the problem by using both the article post that I mentioned in the main post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711134/electron-call-renderer-function-from-main) answer.

Answer (score 11):

Dialog api is available in main process(https://electron.atom.io/docs/).

To create a dialog box you will have to tell your main process to do so by sending a message from renderer process.

Try this code:

```
// in your renderer process:-

const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

ipcRenderer.send('selectDirectory');


//in you main process:-

const electron = require('electron');

const ipcMain = electron.ipcMain;

const dialog = electron.dialog;

//hold the array of directory paths selected by user

let dir;

ipcMain.on('selectDirectory', function() {

    dir = dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {

        properties: ['openDirectory']

    });

});
```

Note: mainWindow here, it's the parent browserWindow which will hold the dialog box.

Comment: As far as I know, Dialog is available in the Renderer.

Comment: I did. Use Remote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use electron remote

```
const {dialog} = require('electron'),
WIN = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

/*
//renderer.js - a renderer process
const {remote} = require('electron'),
dialog = remote.dialog,
WIN = remote.getCurrentWindow();
*/

let options = {
 // See place holder 1 in above image
 title : "Custom title bar", 

 // See place holder 2 in above image
 defaultPath : "D:\\electron-app",

 // See place holder 3 in above image
 buttonLabel : "Custom button",

 // See place holder 4 in above image
 filters :[
  {name: 'Images', extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif']},
  {name: 'Movies', extensions: ['mkv', 'avi', 'mp4']},
  {name: 'Custom File Type', extensions: ['as']},
  {name: 'All Files', extensions: ['*']}
 ],
 properties: ['openFile','multiSelections']
}

//Synchronous
let filePaths = dialog.showOpenDialog(WIN, options)
console.log('filePaths)

//Or asynchronous - using callback
dialog.showOpenDialog(WIN, options, (filePaths) => {
 console.log(filePaths)
})
```

Comment: `Remote` is out in recent versions of Electron.