# electron open default file browser window without returning anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, dialog, ipcmain

I am working on an electron app that can open a directory file picker and return a value, like how this question does it: [Electron - Open Folder Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027287/electron-open-folder-dialog)

```
ipcMain.on('selectDirectory', function() {

    dir = dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {

        properties: ['openDirectory']

    });

});
```

But I cannot find a way to open the folder dialog without returning anything, like if I as a user want to open the location of a file. I don't want to lock my program by waiting for a selected file/folder.
I just want a window to a specific location to open on a user's machine through my cross-platform electron app (mac/win/linux)

Answer (score 0):

Electron's [`dialog.showOpenDialog()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options) returns a promise, so it would need to be handled as such.

```js
ipcMain.on('selectDirectory', function() {

    // Define the options.
    let options = {
        title: "My title",
        properties: ['openDirectory'],
        defaultPath: "/absolute/path/to/open/at"   // Optional.
    }

    // Show the open (folder) dialog.
    dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, options)
        .then((result) => {
            // Bail early if user cancelled dialog.
            if (result.canceled) { return }

            // Get the selected path.
            let path = result.filePaths[0];

            // More processing...
        })
});
```

If you wish to set the inital path the dialog opens at then set the `defaultPath` property.

The `path` variable will give you the path the user selected in the dialog.